# Computing average from return values

Tags: java, random, parameters, while-loop, return

I wondering how to compute "Average # of steps equals" correctly as steps/N does not work in main method. My code runs correctly if I have 100/N instead however I am not sure how to sum up the steps in `TestWalk` method which then gets returned to main. Thanks!

```
class Test { 

static int TestWalk() {

      int location = 5;
      int steps = 0;
      while (location != 0 && location !=10)
      {
         int direction = (int)(Math.random()*2);
         if (direction == 0)
         {
            location = location - 1;
         }
         if (direction == 1)
         {
            location = location + 1;
         }
         steps = steps + 1;
      }
      if (location == 0)
      {
         System.out.println ("Time for a walk!");
         System.out.println ("Took " + steps + " steps, and ");
         System.out.println ("Landed at HOME\n");
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println ("Time for a walk!");
         System.out.println ("Took " + steps + " steps, and ");
         System.out.println ("Landed in Hospital\n");
      }
      return steps; }

      public static void main (String [] args) {
      final int N = 5;
      for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
         TestWalk();
      System.out.println ("Average # of steps equals " + steps/N);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a steps variable in `main()` which will contain the sum of all the steps returned from `TestWalk()`; method.

```
int steps = 0; // this is local to main and has nothing do with the steps in TestWalk() method
for(int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
    steps += TestWalk(); // steps will keep the sum of all the steps
}
System.out.println ("Average # of steps equals " + steps/N);
```

Answer (score 0):

CHange your for method in main to this :

```
int steps = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
   steps += TestWalk();
System.out.println ("Average # of steps equals " + steps/N);
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this..

```
     public static void main (String [] args) {
      final int N = 5;
      int total = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        total+= TestWalk();
      System.out.println ("Average # of steps equals " + total/N);
}
```